# How do the odd proton-number elements originate?

Tags: atoms, elements, periodic-table, atomic-structure, protons

I have a question about the origin of the odd proton-number elements in the periodic table, please.

As it is generally thought that the big bang produces hydrogen first, and then hydrogen combined to form helium. Helium combines into beryllium, and beryllium into carbon, etc... This means that all fusion atoms have even numbers of protons, does not not?

Then, if radioactive decay involving protons always result in a 2 protons decay, how then can we ever end up with atoms of odd number of protons, such as lithium, boron, nitrogen, etc?

Comment: This is question rather for nuclear physics and cosmology. Generally, they are created by the same processes as even-proton nuclei. BTW Li, Be and B are not produced by fusion. See also [Nucleosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleosynthesis). Search also for S-process, R-process and Spallation.

Comment: @Poutnik  According to the Wikipedia article you link, Li-7 can be produced by the fusion of tritium and He-4; and Be-7 can be produced by the fusion of He-3 and He-4.

Comment: @theorist I should say naturally and in majority. You cannot fuse 2 4He to 8Be, unless there is the 3rd 4He to form 12C. 7Be would quickly decay to 7Li.

Comment: @Poutnik  The article described these as the "chief nuclear reactions responsible for the relative abundances of light atomic nuclei observed throughout the universe", indicating these are the primary reactions that gave rise to these isotopes.  Yes, the Be-7 would quickly decay (half-life of 52 days), but Li-7 is stable.  I.e., it's saying the main origin of present-day Li is nuclear fusion.

Comment: @theorist I agree about the lithium, not about Be and B. The info I wrote may come from other source than the link and may be related  to higher than expected abundance of light elements on Earth, assuming the main their source us due Spallation. It is also supported by the periodic table chart in the link.

Comment: Correction: Stable isotopes of Be and B  were not created by nuclear fusion, but by fission by cosmic radiation called [cosmic ray Spallation aka X-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray_spallation).

Comment: More generally, it seems the asker may not be aware of [beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay) (both minus and plus, but especially the former) as a major process capable of converting nuclei with an even number of protons into a nucleus with an odd number of protons.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto yes, thank you... i've forgotten about the decay that converts a proton to a neutron. So the odd numbers can be gotten by this beta decay. Thank you!

Comment: Even ones too. You cannot obtain stable iron nuclei by just adding alpha particles.

Comment: There are several different types of nuclear reaction that can create elements. Small, fresh stars do the one described in the question. But there are different routes to new nuclei that only occur in big stars when they become supernovae (these produce more heavy elements). Even heavier nuclei are thought to come from extreme events like neutron star collisions. Also, many of the elements common on earth are the result of the deaths of the first starts and are not present in the first generation of stars.

Comment: Note, in the English language, chemical names (including elements) are capitalized only at the beginning of a phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most significant sources of an odd-numbered element is the [CNO cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle) that operates to a minor extent in our Sun and more prominently in more massive stars like Sirius. There are actually several CNO cycles, but they all involve carbon, nitrogen and oxygen interchanging through the absorption of protons and the emission of alpha and positron beta particles. The net result is the same as direct hydrogen-to-helium fusion: four protons absorbed into the nuclei during this cycle are converted into one alpha particle and two positrons that are emitted, plus the same energy that we see with the direct fusion. This mechanism is responsible for nitrogen being the second most abundant odd-numbered element in the Universe, behind hydrogen but beating lithium and boron despite the lower atomic numbers of the latter two elements.